# Is the location of gcc.exe for studio running R 4.2.1 on windows 10 causing gcc.exe, the c compiler, to error in compiling?

Tags: c, rstudio

The question is related to the location of gcc.exe, the c compiler, with RStudio and namely rtools42

On the console of RStudio in windows 10, on running  system('where gcc')  the display indicates
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin\gcc.exe

It should be
C:\rtools42\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe

My path indicates that C:\rtools42\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe is almost at the very top.

I have a bad feeling that I might have messed the installation of rtools and before I go and reinstall rtools can you please tell me whether this what you are seeing too?

With RStudio in the Cloud, gcc.exe is correctly located at /usr/bin/gcc

Some of the c compilation with gcc produces errors.

Comment: Please show the exact compilation error messages.

Comment: It sounds like you should be able to find the settings for RStudio and simply correct the location for gcc. If not in the RStudio interface itself, likely in the registry. I've never worked with RStudio, so I can't be more specific, but there are only a few places the path can hide...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the path of gcc to the windows environment variables.